# Verbal agreement? Can I not take this job now and wait for the one that pays more?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, quitting

Okay. I'm a little upset. I went for a job interview and the employer called to offer me the job. The job is nice but nothing too exciting. Then, another employer contacted me to tell me I was being considered for 2 positions that pay substantially more (4-7 dollars more/hour to be exact).

I already told the job that wants to hire me that I'll be in for drug testing. 
Is that a verbal agreement to take the job?

If I take the job and the one that pays more comes along, would I be wrong to quit so quickly if/when the other one comes along?
Should I just call back and say I changed my mind and disappoint them?
Would this likely place me on a "do not hire" list?

Not sure what to do as I can't burn bridges but at the same time I can't pass up better opportunities.

Comment: Can the company take you now and dump you for a better worker when one comes long in a few weeks? How would you feel about being screwed around like that? But it doesnt sound like you have accepted the job, just a precursor hurdle to getting a job offer.

Comment: Three offers within one week seems to indicate that you are in demand and need not worry about missing out on any particular job. - Go for the better job, even though you won't know for two weeks.

Comment: What is a "city job"?

Comment: I'm with Joe - you don't actually have a solid job offer yet.   Do the drug testing (that'll buy you another week or so for results) then, if you actually get the better job offer take that one.

Comment: Also, are you talking to companies themselves or agents. *Do not trust anything an agent tells you verbally*, don't put a position at risk till you have heard from the company itself.

Answer (score 7):

$7/hr is $14,560 in a year, presuming  a 2080 hour year. I don't imagine that's an irrelevant sum of money to you. And the higher paying job might come with more responsibility and more opportunity for growth.

I think you respect yourself, and yours and your loved ones' futures enough to reach for the higher rung, don't you?  :-)

Why don't you alter whatever other plans you have, prioritize interviewing and doing drug tests for the second potential employer ASAP, then if it still isn't decided go ahead and do the other drug test as planned. You're not obligated to tell either of them you're interviewing with the other. You're not responsible to them as an employee until you sign an employment contract, and neither are they. The drug test is really still part of the interview.

**EDIT:** There is risk in just about anything you do. Hesitating on the first job to check out the others could put the first job at risk, and there is no guarantee that you'll get either of the other jobs. The first one sounds like a relatively sure thing, presuming the drug test isn't an issue. So the *safe* course might be to just take the first job, and that might certainly be the *best* choice as well, if you need it. But it also sounds like you have at least a week that you can afford to play with. If you can hold on for a little while and check out the other jobs, the reward might be worth the short-term sacrifice. Or, of course, you could end up three weeks from now still looking for a job.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the second one that I really want says they won't get back to me for another two weeks.  :O :O
I hate these kinds of dilemmas. I feel like my reputation is at stake because I logically can't pass up more money and what I really want, but this first company really wants me.

Comment: @Questions Can you absorb an extra week or two without pay? If the first one wants you that badly, would they wait, if you respectfully ask them to? You still wouldn't be obligated to give them all the reasons why. I would think that you could take the drug test then respectfully tell them you need a week to make a final decision. They would say whatever they say to that. But it doesn't seem unreasonable, and if they want you that badly I would think they would respond respectfully. They might say they just can't wait, but I wouldn't think they'd rescind the offer just because you asked.

Comment: @Craig There is no guarantee that the OP will be offered the second job.  Do you wait two weeks, only to find that you have no job at all?

Comment: @JaneS That's certainly true. For that matter there's no guarantee I'll make it to the office instead of the hospital tomorrow, either. But that isn't going to stop me from trying. Taking what appears to be the no-risk (low-reward) option is certainly an available choice and I wouldn't judge anybody for a second for making it.

Comment: @Craig Then your answer needs to indicate that this is a risky strategy, and that there is a reasonable chance that they will end up with no job.  I know that I certainly could not afford to go jobless, the OP doesn't indicate either way.

Comment: @JaneS That's why I asked a couple of comments back if the OP could afford to go an extra week without pay, and suggested options in my answer to check out both options without throwing the first one away. I don't know about high risk, but there's certainly risk--in everything. Having said that, I will update my answer slightly. I genuinely respect your take on this and your concern. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First - if you don't have a *written* offer, even with a drug test as a contigency, you don't have anything enforceable if the employer decides to not bring you on.  Request a written offer letter.

Second, the first "offer" (phrased loosely) is *like* a bird in the hand.  With the other job, they could be blowing smoke up your butt.  Be reasonable, and don't make quick decisions based on greed.  The few weeks could easily turn into months, or no call back at all.  Employers do this all the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, people calling you can say whatever they want.  If they want you, they'll get you to sign a piece of paper.